# New navigation : newest and recently active inverted in recommended mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

While showing recommended questions :

**Recently active sorting** shows **new questions :**

[image]

**Newest questions sorting** shows **recently active questions :**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean they're inverted?

Comment: @Scimonster I mean the behavior and the name of the criteria don't match.

Comment: "Recently active" _appears to be_ correct. [But "Newest" definitely is not correct.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256853/159034)