# New questions, Show Recommended, Sort Newest not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Select <kbd>New questions</kbd>, show <kbd>Recommended</kbd> and sort by <kbd>Newest</kbd> and the [top question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061837/catching-errors-in-global-asax) in my list is from 2012:

[image: Example of questions]

## EDIT

The very old questions now appear to be gone (yay) but the ordering seems inconsistent (boo):

[image]

Comment: It isn't even ordered in sequence...

Comment: Blimey, I just got a downvote for this, very random :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed: there was a missing template. It's being deployed now.

Comment: Has this fix been rolled out yet? I'm still seeing the problem the OP described.