# Recommended + all + newest sorts in reverse order (oldest first)

Tags: bug, sorting, new-nav

This is similar to [New questions, Show Recommended, Sort Newest not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256853/new-questions-show-recommended-sort-newest-not-working). The ordering is correct, but instead shows the oldest questions first.

[image: space]

The newest posts end up at the bottom of the second page. The other sort/filter combinations seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved according to [New nav appears to sort newest recommended questions in reverse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297631/new-nav-appears-to-sort-newest-recommended-questions-in-reverse) (this question being an apparent duplicate of that one).